# Angular application stops when subscribing to api response

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm at my wits end trying to work out what I've done wrong in my Angular 6 application.  The problem with the below code is that it 'should' work, but my angular application just stops and won't continue.

Note that all my other API calls and similar code is working ok.

I've added in console logs to try to find out what's going on:

I have a form that I'm submitting:

```
submit(f) {
  console.log('2')
  // Now I'm saving the data, this works
  this.userService.completeProfile(this.model)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('3')
        // this is to get a new token
        this.authService.getNewToken(this.model.id)
          .pipe(first())
          .subscribe(() =>
            data => {
              // I never get to 8
              console.log('8')
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/register/profile/complete');
            },
            error => {
              console.log('9')
            }
          );

      },
      error => {
          console.log('10')
      });

}
```

This is my auth service:

```
private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<LoggedInUser>({} as LoggedInUser);
currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

setCurrentUser(): void {
    if (localStorage.getItem("auth_token")) {
        let jwtData = localStorage.getItem("auth_token").split('.')[1]
        let decodedJwtJsonData = window.atob(jwtData)
        let decodedJwtData = JSON.parse(decodedJwtJsonData)

        this.currentUserSubject.next(
            {
                name: decodedJwtData.name,
                id: decodedJwtData.id,
            }
        );
    }
}

getNewToken(id: String) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + '/GetNewToken', { id: id })
    .pipe(map(user => {
        console.log(user)
        if (user && user.auth_token) {
            console.log("4")
            //localStorage.setItem('auth_token', user.auth_token);
            console.log("5")
            //this.setCurrentUser();
            console.log("6")
        }
        console.log("7")
        return user;
    }));
}
```

The console output stops at 7

Comment: instead of logging a number that has 0 informative character, try to console.log the data, or better replace it with `debugger;`

Comment: Right now I'm trying to work out where the code is going.  If I replace the console.log('8) with logging the data, nothing happens as the code never gets there

Comment: @RobbieMills And how far does it get?

Comment: 7. I have that in the code comments, but edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the wrong `subscribe(...)` implementation. Its parameters are functions (next, error, complete) that are immediately invoked when the related events occur, but you are passing a function that returns an object with `data` and `error` inner functions that will never be invoked.

Try changing the section like this:

```
this.authService.getNewToken(this.model.id)
          .pipe(first())
          .subscribe(data =>
            {
              // I never get to 8
              console.log('8')
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/register/profile/complete');
            },
            error => {
              console.log('9')
            }
          );
```

Comment: That's perfect, I don't know how I missed that, thank you!